# Web API Contoller - What is the proper format of the data to be returned

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API controller that retrieves ticket information. At the start -- The API is called and the request is routed to the proper controller function.  The controller passes a request to the database. From there the retrieved data is ran through a dictionary block where the field name is associated with the data. Next the data is serialized. Then the data is passed back to the controller. At this point I know the Json string looks good. But, when the properly formatted json data is passed back to the caller a bunch slashes are added to the output.

My understanding is that Web API is supposed to automatically format the return data. I suspect I am formatting the data for the controller correctly before it is returned.

```
    Public Function GetTicketSearch(ByVal SourceTktNum As String) As Object

    'GET api/outage/SourceTktNum

    Dim strFullName As String = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.FullName
    Dim strMethodName As String = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
    Dim strClassRoutine As String = strMethodName & " / " & strFullName

    Try

        Dim objJsonRptRtn As Object = GetReportData_bllBLL.BLL__DataSet__GetReportData__GetData(strMARCLSysId, strLogonSysId, SourceTktNum)

        'AT THIS POINT I KNOW THE JSON STRING LOOKS AS IT SHOULD.

        Return objJsonRptRtn

        'AFTER THE ABOVE STATEMENT SOMETHING HAPPENS TO THE DATA / SLASHES ARE ADDED TO THE OUTPUT TO BE RETURNED BY THE API

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim strExMessage As String = ex.Message
        Dim strStackTrace As String = ex.StackTrace

        Dim strMsg As String = strExMessage & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.Lf & strStackTrace & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.Lf

        MailLogEvent.BLL__Process__MailAndLogEvent__AddLogEntry(strMARCLSysId, strLogonSysId, 901020, dteTime_Start, 0, strMsg, strClassRoutine)

        Throw New HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)

    End Try

End Function
```

Code to create  JSON object to be passed back to the controller...

```
        '--------------------------------------------------------- Create Json String

        Dim dctDataDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        dctDataDictionary.Add("sourceTktNum", strSourceTktNumKey)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("incidentTime", strIncidentTime)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("incidentEndTime", strIncidentEndTime)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("recordTimeStamp", strRecordTimeStamp)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("outageReasonCd", strOutageReasonCd)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numDS3", strNumDS3)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numBlocked", strNumBlocked)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numVOIP", strNumVOIP)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numWireline", strNumWireline)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numEndUserCircuits", strNumEndUserCircuits)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("stateCd", strStateCd)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("city", strCity)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("incidentDescription", strIncidentDescription)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("causeDesc", strCauseDesc)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("equipFailedDesc", strEquipFailedDesc)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("networkPartDesc", strNetworkPartDesc)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("restoreMethodDesc", strRestoreMethodDesc)

        objJsonRptRtn = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dctDataDictionary)

        Return objJsonRptRtn
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because you are again trying to convert a json data into json, which results in extra slashes.
Can you show the code before you return 'objJsonRptRtn'.

Comment: I am almost 100% sure that is what is going on. In the BLL code I am creating a dictionary where I bind the field name to the data. The next thing I do is sterilize the data to Json. I remember reading that the API also does this automatically. What would help me is to find out how to prepare the data before the API serializes it and passes it back to the caller.

Comment: instead of creating a dictionary, create an object with all those fields and return that without passing it to the serializer

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out I was double serializing. I removed the statement that serialized the dictionary output. Then, simply passed the dictionary back to the controller then let the controller return the dictionary. Everything works great...

```
          '--------------------------------------------------------- Create Dictionary

        dctDataDictionary.Add("sourceTktNum", strSourceTktNumKey)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("incidentTime", strIncidentTime)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("incidentEndTime", strIncidentEndTime)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("recordTimeStamp", strRecordTimeStamp)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("outageReasonCd", strOutageReasonCd)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numDS3", strNumDS3)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numBlocked", strNumBlocked)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numVOIP", strNumVOIP)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numWireline", strNumWireline)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("numEndUserCircuits", strNumEndUserCircuits)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("stateCd", strStateCd)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("city", strCity)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("incidentDescription", strIncidentDescription)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("causeDesc", strCauseDesc)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("equipFailedDesc", strEquipFailedDesc)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("networkPartDesc", strNetworkPartDesc)
        dctDataDictionary.Add("restoreMethodDesc", strRestoreMethodDesc)

        Return dctDataDictionary

Public Function GetTicketSearch(ByVal SourceTktNum As String) As Object

    'GET api/outage/SourceTktNum

    Dim strFullName As String = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.FullName
    Dim strMethodName As String = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
    Dim strClassRoutine As String = strMethodName & " / " & strFullName

    Try

        Dim dctDataDictionary As Object = GetReportData_bllBLL.BLL__DataSet__GetReportData__GetData(strMARCLSysId, strLogonSysId, SourceTktNum)

        If dctDataDictionary Is Nothing Then
            Throw New HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent)
        Else
            Return dctDataDictionary
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim strExMessage As String = ex.Message
        Dim strStackTrace As String = ex.StackTrace

        Dim strMsg As String = strExMessage & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.Lf & strStackTrace & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.Lf

        MailLogEvent.BLL__Process__MailAndLogEvent__AddLogEntry(strMARCLSysId, strLogonSysId, 901020, dteTime_Start, 0, strMsg, strClassRoutine)

        Throw New HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)

    End Try

End Function
```